# How to select and option from a select dropdown using JS

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason I am having a hard time using the value of an option in a select dropdown.  Here is the code:

```
<select id="select_category" name="select_category">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="home">Home</option>
  <option value="office">Office</option>
  <option value="dinning_room">Dinning Room</option>
</select>

<script>
var select_category = document.getElementById("select_category");
select_category.options["home"].selected = true;
</script>
```

When I run this I get the error "Cannot set propery 'selected' of undefined. If I replace ["home"] with [2] in the last line it works. Why can't I reference the option via the value I assigned to it?

Thanks

EDIT - as suggested, changed the javascript to this below, but now I get the error "token ILLEGAL"

```
document.getElementById('select_category').value = 'home';​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: document.getElementById('select_category').value = 'home';​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select_category.options["home"].selected = true;
```

This line isn't working because  options requires an index (ie the number, as you discovered above).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp

Give each option a name and use this:

```
select_category.options.namedItem("nameGoesHere").selected = true;
```

Alternatively, you can give each option an id and use:

```
document.getElementById("home").selected = true;
```

(assuming the id of the option is "home" in this case.

Comment: How can I then set a certain option as selected using the value (should I put an ID on each option?)

Comment: If you put an id on each option that would be fine. Value is just used to display text to the user. Since you can potentially have two options with the same value, it isn't useable as a unique identifier. With id's, if you have id="home", then you know exactly which one options["home"] is referring to since you can't have more than one option with id="home". That's why value isn't used as an identifier.

Comment: Ok, tried doing that and now get the error "unexpected identifier". now each option is defined <option id="home_option" value="home">Home</option>.... and the JS is: var select_category = document.getElementById("select_category");     select_category.options["home_option"].selected = true;

Comment: You can actually just do document.getElementById("home_option").selected = true;

Comment: I lied to you. Sorry. I re-did my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('select_category').value = 'home';​​​​​​​​​​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/5CgkM/)

Comment: This is actually a much better way to do it than what I suggested.

Comment: But how do I then set the selected item to that one?

Comment: @LuisP That's exactly what it does. Use the jsFiddle demo I posted to try the other options.

Comment: @DevlshOne I cannot get it to work. Essentially this is for a dynamically created select statement for which I want to set the option which I receive via a variable. When I removed my two lines of JS and just added yours I got the error "Unexpected token Illegal"

Comment: If it's for a dynamically created `select` statement, you're going to need to use jQuery so you can delegate events or add `.addEventListeners` in your JS. Are you trying to stick to pure JS?

Comment: Ideally yes since I don't know jQuery.  The JS does not need to set the option prior to rendering, it can do it afterwards.  Essentially it is a dropdown which the user selected in the prior page.  My original code works fine as long as I use the option[2] instead of option["home"].  So my problem is how do I reference the option selected using the value rather than the index.

Comment: @LuisP Just add id's to your options that are the same as your value attribute. Eg. name="home" id="home". Better yet, make the id "home_option" to avoid potential conflicts with other ids, and create the "home_option" text to use in select_category.options[___text___].selected ... by appending "_option" to the value from the previous page (assuming "home" would be passed from the prior page in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Because options is an array. You could write a function like this, though:

```
function selectOptionByValue (select, value) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++ ) {
        select.options[i].selected = select.options[i].value === value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`document.getElementById("select_category").options[1].selected = true;`

If you want to set it via the value use this:

`document.getElementById('select_category').value = 'home';​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it via the values since this is coming from a variable

Comment: I tried doing what you said but now I get a 'token illegal' error (see edit above).

Comment: Do you want to set the value, before the element gets rendered?

Comment: No, not necessary, I just want it to show the right option (which was the one selected in the prior page)